# Liquid theme product field item to cart

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have been trying to add a custom field to my product and it's showing in product page but not in the cart.

I have been going through the steps from : https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/product-pages-get-customization-information-for-produ...

I have added an example field in main.product.liquid

```
          <p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label for="your-name">Your name</label>
  <textarea required class="required" id="your-name" name="properties[Your name]"></textarea>
</p>
```

and then I have added this to main-cart-items.liquid

```
{% assign property_size = item.properties | size %}
{% if property_size > 0 %}
  {% for p in item.properties %}
    {% assign first_character_in_key = p.first | truncate: 1, '' %}
    {% unless p.last == blank or first_character_in_key == '_' %}
      {{ p.first }}:
      {% if p.last contains '/uploads/' %}
        <a class="lightbox" href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
      {% else %}
        {{ p.last }}
      {% endif %}
      <br>
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I am running out of ideas can someone help ?

Comment: you add a textarea, and try to list a file into cart page, can you please check it and implement it properly. copy paste code from any place doesn't work each time.

Comment: Is this code 
`<p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label for="your-name">Your name</label>
  <textarea required class="required" id="your-name" name="properties[Your name]"></textarea>
</p>` 
inside your {% form %} tag?

Comment: The line item property code for the cart is already in the theme so I think the  property isn't being posted, you need to associate the field with the form this usually can be done by having the field inside the {% form %} tag or else associated with the form by giving it the attribute form="{{ product_form_id }}"

Comment: @pete Just wanted to let you know that adding the attribute forn on the input worked. Feel free to raise a proper answer that I can give a green tick to . Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above to handle the line item property is already in the theme, so the property isn't being posted, you need to associate the field with the form this usually can be done by having the field inside the {% form %} tag or else associated with the form by giving it the attribute form="{{ product_form_id }}"